# Image not found with Path

Tags: html, angular

My folder structure looks like

```
-node_modules
-src
  index.html
  -app
    -home-page
      -home-page.component.html
      -img
        -header.jpg
```

Inside my home-page.component.html, I have the following code

> ```
> <img src="/src/app/home-page/img/header.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="">
> ```

However, when I run the app, I get the following error

```
GET http://localhost:4200/src/app/home-page/img/header.jpg 404 (Not Found)
```

However, when I command click (on Mac) on that link inside src, I get re-directed to the image with no problem.

I have also tried

```
./img/header.jpg
```

Comment: try removing preceding /(slash) if src is a root folder.

Comment: How do you pack your assets? If you happen to use the angular-cli be sure to add your img folder to the assets array.

Comment: What URL do you use to call your home-page.component.html file?